# TypeError: Error #1009:Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, typeerror

I have been trying to fix the above error since yesterday late into the night.
Today i tried again for many hours. I learned a great deal and understand a lot more. I found some things along the way and fixed them, unfortunatly the error persisted.

**I now know for example 
that the above error indicates that one of the objects being targeted by my code is out of scope.**
Caused possibly by:

1. It being declared but not instantiated
2. It doesn't have an instance name (or the instance name is misspelled)
3. It does not exist in the frame where that code is trying to talk to it
4. It is animated into place but is not assigned instance names in every keyframe for it
5. It is one of two or more consecutive keyframes of the same objects with no name (or a different name) assigned in the preceding frame(s).

***This is the error line where it goes wrong:***

```
if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
```

**So it has to be something with back or collosions...**

1. I checked and it's not a misspeled instance
   BTW back is a background movieclip with Back instance and it contains the collisions image with instance Collisions
2. it is being declared (but possibly not right)
3. Could be the cause. frame 1 is the preloader. frame 2 is the menu with a button to start code cat.as. Frame 3 contains the game
4. it only exists on one keyframe so it isn't mistake number 4
5. it only exists on one keyframe so it isn't mistake number 5

So it's most likely number 3.

What i think happens is that i click on the button and it immediatly wants to run cat.as before going to frame 3. How should i solve this. I'm thinking of placing the game on frame 2 but offscreen. 
I would very much like feedback on this, please. Thanks

***My code: EDIT: i gave the var public***

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Cat extends MovieClip
{

    public var leftPressedfBoolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;

    public var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var upBumping:Boolean = false;
    public var downBumping:Boolean = false;

    public var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30,-55);
    public var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30,-55);
    public var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,-120);
    public var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,0);

    public var scrollX:Number = 0;
    public var scrollY:Number = 500;

    public var xSpeed:Number = 0;
    public var ySpeed:Number = 0;

    public var speedConstant:Number = 4;
    public var frictionConstant:Number = 0.9;
    public var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
    public var jumpConstant:Number = -35;
    public var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;

    public var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
    public var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

    public var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
    public var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

    public var currentLevel:int = 1;

    public var animationState:String = "idle";

    public var bulletList:Array = new Array();
    public var enemyList:Array = new Array();
    public var bumperList:Array = new Array();

    public var player:Player;
    public var back:Back;
    public var sky:Sky;
    public var collisions:Collisions;
    public var visuals:Visuals;
    public var other:Other;
    public var doorKey:DoorKey;

    public function Cat()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    public function init(e:Event):void

{
        player = new Player();
        back = new Back();
        sky = new Sky();
        visuals = new Visuals();
        other = new Other();            
        collisions = new Collisions();
        doorKey = new DoorKey();

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        addEnemiesToLevel1();
        addBumpersToLevel1();
    }

    public function addEnemiesToLevel1():void
    {
        addEnemy(620, -115);
        addEnemy(900, -490);
        addEnemy(2005, -115);
        addEnemy(1225, -875);
    }

    public function addBumpersToLevel1():void
    {
        addBumper(500, -115);
        addBumper(740, -115);
    }


    public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if (back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
        {
            //trace("leftBumping");
            leftBumping = true;
        }
        else
        {
            leftBumping = false;
        }
```

Comment: I revised my answwer.  You have to add the player to the stage before you can get it's x val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your if statement to see which item is missing:

```
trace("back "+back);
trace("back.collisions "+back.collisions);
trace("player.x "+player.x);
trace("leftBumpPoint.x "+leftBumpPoint.x);
trace("player.y "+player.y);
trace("leftBumpPoint.y "+leftBumpPoint.y);
```

Comment: back [object Back]
    back.collisions null
    player.x 0
    leftBumpPoint.x -30
    player.y 0
    leftBumpPoint.y -55

Comment: so back.collisions = null hmmm

Comment: You have created a variable named collisions, so you should be able to access this directly. e.g. collisions.hitTestPoint, not back.collisions.hitTestPoint

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Very gratefull! I think this solved the problem. When i removed the back as you suggested it works. It does give a new error further down the code. But thanks to you and the other guys I can continue to work on this will try to solve the next error (which is BTW TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject for this line : if (player.hitTestObject(other.doorKey))

Comment: i fixed this error myself but now the player is stuck on stage and rapidly going through it;s animation....hmm

Comment: Are you testing your swf (cmd+enter) or debugging (Debug menu > Debug Movie)? Usually debugging will give you more information on exactly what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your never adding player to the stage before checking to see what it's x value is.

Comment: Where are your addEnemy() & addBumber() methods?  Your extending movieClip

Comment: Ok thanks will get right on it. This is probably the correct awnser

Comment: apperently it's not nessescary (but i could be wrong) It still seems to get the x and y value in the code. After running a trace. x = 0 y = 0 this is probably because the player is placed in a frame on the timeline

Answer (score 0):

You declare back and collisions separately, but you're accessing them with collisions being a property of back.  Does back have a collisions property?   If so, how is it initialized?

Comment: Do you mean i should declare them together?

Comment: what would it look like : back having a collisions property

Comment: This seems to be the problem. I'm researching how to give back a collisions property. If anyone has a link to the subject or wants to leave the awnser here very much appreciated

Comment: Back and Collisions are separate classes - what are you trying to do with these?  If you want Collisions to be part of Back, then you need to create a Collisions var in the Back class.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! It's a shame I can't select 2 awnsers as being the right awnser.

Answer (score 0):

per your statement

> back is a background movieclip with Back instance

I can assume you set "Back" as the instance name for a movieClip "back"

Changing "back" to "Back" should do it

Comment: ? i think you misunderstood because i wasn't clear on this. the movieclip is called "Background" the as linkage/instance name is Back. And it's public var back:Back;

Comment: just to be save i now called the movieclip Back also. but it still gives the error